# Spring not loading properties

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

Spring not loading properties when applicationContext.xml is referenced in a @Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class SpringConfig {

  @Autowired
    private MyBean1 myBean1;

  @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

    }

  @Bean(name = "myBean2")
    public MyBean2 myBean2() {
    MyBean2 bean2 = new MyBean2();
    return bean2;
    }


}
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
       <property name="location">           
                <value>classpath:test.properties</value>           
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="myBean1" class="com.foo.bar.MyBean1">
        <property name="name" value="${name}" />  
        <property name="age" value="${age}" />  
    </bean>
```

**Test.properties:** (in the classpath)

```
name=foo
age=10
```

When I load the applicationContext.xml file using the following lines of code, it worked:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

I see the following lines printed:

```
2015-05-30 10:01:08.277 [INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [test.properties]
2015-05-30 10:01:08.292 [INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory:596 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5c001eb0: defining beans [placeholderConfig,myBean1]; root of factory hierarchy
```

I have no issues loading the test.properties file with "myBean1" getting the value of ${name} and {age} from the properties file.

The issue I have is when I try to load SpringConfig:

```
ApplicationContext ctx =   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

The SpringConfig class refers to applicationContext.xml as: @ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")

The error I am seeing is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'myBean1' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in string value "${name}"
                            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
                            at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:174)
                            at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
                            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
                            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
                            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
                            at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
```

In a nutshell, when I load applicationContext using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, then I have no issue:

**Working:**

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

But when it is referred by SpringConfig, then I see that applicationContext does not see my properties file.

**Not Working:**

ApplicationContext ctx =   new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

Please note that test.properties is in my classpath and it is nothing to do with the properties file missing or something.

I don't know if I have to use a different approach for AnnotationConfigApplicationContext as I need myBean1 to be auto-wired into SpringConfig and myBean1 uses some properties from the test.properties file.

Comment: "In the classpath" ~ Where? Under `resources`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

you're registering two `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` beans that are used to resolve properties. One through Java

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

}
```

and one through the imported XML

```
<bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="location">           
            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>           
    </property>
</bean>
```

The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean is fail-fast when it comes to resolving properties. That is, if it doesn't find a match, it will throw an exception (actually the nested class that does the resolution will do that).

Since your `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` hasn't been initialized with any `locations`, it doesn't have any sources from where to resolve `${name}` or `${age}` (it has some sources, but not your `test.properties` file).

Either set up your bean correctly to find your properties file

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("test.properties"));
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}
```

or remove it entirely. If you do remove it, Spring will use the correctly configured `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean from XML.